# Gradle issue while importing Android Link Preview library

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, preview

I'm importing Android link preview in my project(https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview) but it is giving me the error while running the project

```
Task failed with an exception.
 -----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
 > Could not find com.leocardz:link-preview:2.0.0.
 Searched in the following locations:
   - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/leocardz/link-preview/2.0.0/link-preview-2.0.0.pom
   - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/leocardz/link-preview/2.0.0/link-preview-2.0.0.pom
   - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/leocardz/link-preview/2.0.0/link-preview-2.0.0.pom
   - https://github.com/leonardocardoso/mvn-repo/raw/master/maven-deploy/com/leocardz/link-preview/2.0.0/link-preview-2.0.0.pom
 Required by:
     project :app
```

settings.gradle

```
pluginManagement {
repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://github.com/leonardocardoso/mvn-repo/raw/master/maven-deploy' }
}
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://github.com/leonardocardoso/mvn-repo/raw/master/maven-deploy' }
}
}


implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.5.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.1'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1' // required
implementation 'com.leocardz:link-preview:2.0.0@aar'
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. You can get library code directly to your project and remove dependencies from gradle files.

https://github.com/LeonardoCardoso/Android-Link-Preview/tree/master/library/src/main/java/com/leocardz/link/preview/library

You just need to add these codes to your project.